# Atom - changing keyboard shortcuts for defult actions

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

the **delete line** function in the **[atom-editor](/questions/tagged/atom-editor)** on Mac is assigned to <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>. I've a two questions:

1. How can I reassign this action to <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>?
2. Follow-up with the first one, is there a convenient way of browsing existing command and assigned keyboard shortcuts?

---

*I would be obliged if the answer would provide a comprehensive extract `keymap.cson` file **and/or** any other files that have to be modified to make this work.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with the second part of your question, since it gives you an understanding of what we're going to do. There are two ways to find existing keybindings:

1. Open settings, click on *Keybindings* and type `delete-line`. Words are *usually* separated by a single dash, though there are exceptions such as `newline`.
2. Install the [`keybinding-resolver`](https://atom.io/packages/keybinding-resolver) and open it using the <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> shortcut. The resolver will display any shortcut as you type.

Both options will display the triggered command and the selector in which the shortcut is working. In our case the command is `editor:delete-line` and the selector `atom-text-editor:not([mini])`. We will use both when creating our custom keybinding.

Open the keymap from the menu (*Atom* > *Keymap*) or the command palette (*“Application: Open Your Keymap”*). I've commented a working example to explain each step:

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  # Unbind default Cmd-D shortcut
  'cmd-d': 'unbind!' 

  # Assign new shortcut
  'cmd-d': 'editor:delete-line'

  # Optional: Unbind default editor:delete-line shortcut
  'ctrl-shift-k': 'unbind!'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not working for me it's showing "Duplicate key 'cmd-d'", what I should do here?

Answer (score 0):

Found [another discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-can-i-change-the-keymap-to-have-delete-line-working-with-cmd-d/6460/12) and adding the following to the keymap (Atom > Keymap) did the trick for me in Atom 1.34.0 :

```
'.platform-darwin atom-text-editor':
  'cmd-d': 'editor:delete-line'
```